# NodeJs retorno função - Consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, funções

Não estou conseguindo retornar valor na função, sei que está errado, mas já fiz várias tentativas sem sucesso. A consulta está sendo realizada e traz a senha, o problema é retornar esse valor para quem executou a função:

```
function obtemSenha() {
    var read_R = 'select * from senha';
    var ret = 0;
    connect.getConnection(function(err, connection){
      connection.query(read_R, function(err, data, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(`SenhaREC....0: ${data[0].senha}`);
            ret = data[0].senha;
            connection.release();
        }
      });
   });
   return ret;
};

var senha = obtemSenha();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca trabalhei com Node.js+MySQL, mas a julgar que operações de IO em Node.js são assíncronas, imagino que o `return` não irá funcionar, pois você está tentando retornar uma variável antes que ela receba o valor do banco de dados. Experimente usar uma **promise**:

```
function obtemSenha() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var read_R = 'select * from senha';
        var ret = 0;
        connect.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.query(read_R, function(err, data, fields) {
                if(err) reject(err);                
                console.log(`SenhaREC....0: ${data[0].senha}`);
                connection.release();
                resolve(data[0].senha);
            });
        });
    });
}

async function foo() {
    try {
        var senha = await obtemSenha();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Erro', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!  Valeu!!!